# TinyButStrong: including a file dynamically

Tags: php, tinybutstrong

How would you set an include file dynamically from a set variables in a php file?

```
<body>
    {onload;file={tplvar.absopath}}
</body>
```

So, once the template is loaded, `$tbs->LoadTemplate($tpl)` the file should produce the html built on the file `absopath` points to.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner down voting for family tree question? is this stackoverflow or NCIS?

Comment: you shouldn't use your sock puppet to upvote the post here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am lost please exit my thread because your harassing me now

Comment: The word is "you're" as in "you are", not "your" as in "ownership". Btw, if anyone's at fault here, it's you. I have nothing to feel guilty about. Or, which "Kevin" am I speaking with here? You, or [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108487/kevin-wiggins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `file` can insert the contents of a file inside the TBS template.

**Examples**

PHP side:

```
$filename = 'header.html';
```

Template side:

```
[onload;file=[var.filename]]
```

See [parameter file](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm_file)

Comment: what if the $filename='header.html' is defined inside of a block?

Comment: i guess you could expose the $filename to a global space but is there a way to send that filename with the template? versus giving it global access?

Comment: `[onload;file=[var.filename]] ` will be merged when the template is loaded, that is before any MergeBlock(). This is better for performance. While `[onshow;file=[var.filename]] ` will be merged before Show(), that is after any MergeBlock().

Comment: In the snippet, `$filename` is supposed to be a global variable. But you can use local variables using VarRef. See http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#php_varref

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable containing a filename, then you can use that with `require` or `include` (with or without `_once`).

For example:

```
<?php
$template = __DIR__.'/templates/header.php';
require_once $template;
```

sort of thing.

This would be an extremely crude way of including a template file, but it is as simple as you can get.

Comment: Check the edits. I need to dynamically create the include once the template is loaded from a tinybutstrong class object